# Buzzing/Static sound in headphones when volume is turned up

Tags: sound, headphones

I can hear a buzzing/static sound in my headphones, especially when the volume is high. When i actually play any audio the buzzing/static sound goes away, So its not really a big problem. This problem only happens with the headphones on.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, How can i fix this?

Comment: Not an answer but a thought. Depending on where the headphone cables is running it might be some kind of magnetic or elec interference. I have also noticed that if my cell phone is close to my comp and i get a call/text that it makes static/buzz noise. Just a thought not a fix

Answer (score 7):

For me this was because my microphone was set to be amplified back to my headphones. If you happen to have a mic, just check to make sure your own voice isn't being amplified. If it is, play around with alsamixer (in my case it was one of the playback sliders) until your own voice is no longer amplified.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use Skype? I had the same problem when I allowed Skype to adjust the audio settings. After unchecking that option in Skype, the humming is gone.

Comment: I was searching a fix for long time. Thanks for Sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is older, but for me this happens when I have "Mic Boost" turned up in alsamixer. Turned that down always removes any buzzing on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off the "Loopback Mix" in alsamixer and it went away. It was essentially the headphone audio being looped to the headphones/speakers.

Answer (score -1):

Unplug your audio on the motherboard and plug it back in, now it should work... I had the same problem and I thought I had just blown out my turtle beaches.